# Layer names changed after reclassification of rasterstack, R

Tags: r, reclassify, rasterstack, layer-name

Following one of my previous questions about looping through a `rasterstack` ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309594/looping-a-raster-stack-with-a-step-r)), I now face a different issue. My initial rasterstack had dates as names (e.g. `X2000_05_08.1`) and I reclassified it in order to change specific values. After the reclassification though, I got a `raster brick` and the names changed from dates to `layer.1`, `layer.2` and so on.

Can anyone help me to understand what I did wrong and how to fix this as I want to keep the dates?

Reclassify code:

```
m <- c(-1, 0,NA) 
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE) # matrix with the value to reclass
new_rc <- reclassify(new, rclmat,right=FALSE) # reclassify my stack ("new")
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the example in the help for `reclassify` (because we can't run your code because we don't have your `new` object)...

If a raster has names:

```
> names(r)="Region-A"
```

and is reclassified....

```
> rc <- reclassify(r, rclmat)
```

the name is not preserved:

```
> names(rc)
[1] "layer"
```

This also applies if you have a stack:

```
> s = stack(r,r,r,r,r,r,r)
```

with names...

```
> names(s)=paste0("Region ",LETTERS[1:7])
```

and reclassify:

```
> sc <- reclassify(s, rclmat)
> names(sc)
[1] "layer.1" "layer.2" "layer.3" "layer.4" "layer.5" "layer.6" "layer.7"
```

the fix is to reset the names on the reclassified stack from the original stack:

```
> names(sc) = names(s)
> names(sc)
[1] "Region.A" "Region.B" "Region.C" "Region.D" "Region.E" "Region.F" "Region.G"
>
```

If you do this a lot then write a wrapper (untested, but should be something like):

```
nreclassify = function(r, ...){
  rc = reclassify(r, ...)
  names(rc) = names(r)
  return(rc)
 }
```

you might also consider suggesting it as an enhancement to the raster package, but the author might have a good reason for not doing this by default.